# How to install graphic drivers for Intel GM45

Tags: dell, intel-graphics, games, intel, error-handling

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Dell laptop whose configuration is as follows:

- Intel Core 2 Duo Processor T6400;
- Intel GMA 4500 MHD Graphics Processor

When I tried to launch a Game "Call Of Duty" using `winetricks`. An error is displayed saying `install drivers for your graphic devices`.

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

intel graphic cards are not very good - you may be better off using a better one. does the graphics card work with more Linux compatible games - e.g FlightGear?

[Found a review here](http://pcgamingcorner.com/?p=820) - it says that it only runs Call of Duty 4 at half a decent frame-rate on a Windows PC, using the same graphics card and similar processor.

Running things using wine can be a tad tricky, as it does not fully interface with the computer.

Sorry, not very experienced with this stuff, but hope this helps.